# Excel Multiple PeopleID, linked to multiple Metadata

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a issue, where i have a record of 1,000 People ID duplicated for each metadata.

Is it possible to use excel to change Table A into table B (below) using a formular?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may *try*, assuming you are using **MS365**, then,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(A3:A11),
w,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(" | ",,FILTER(B3:B11,A3:A11=a)))),
CHOOSE({1,2},u,w))
```

---

Or, using `VSTACK()` & `HSTACK()` exclusively works with **MS365 Office Insiders Beta Version**.

• Formula used in cell `E10`

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(A3:A11),
w,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(" | ",,FILTER(B3:B11,A3:A11=a)))),
VSTACK(A2:B2,HSTACK(u,w)))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `E18`

```
=ListMetadata(A2:B11)
```

The above formula is a custom & reusable formula created using `LAMBDA()` with a friendly name and used in name manager,

```
=LAMBDA(array,
LET(one,DROP(array,1,-1),
two,DROP(array,1,1),
header,TAKE(array,1),
u,UNIQUE(one),
w,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(" | ",,FILTER(two,one=a)))),VSTACK(header,HSTACK(u,w))))
```

---

**Note:** Functions `TAKE()`, `DROP()`, `VSTACK()` and `HSTACK()` are not in regular channels of **MS365** exclusively available to **MS365 Office Insiders Beta Version Only.**